# Django How to concatenate strings in the static reference

Tags: html, django

How do I add the value in card.set to `src="{% static 'images/Magic/4th Edition/Armageddon.full.jpg' %}"` in place of 4th Edition?

```
{% for card in sets %} 
<div class="one-third column portfolio-item">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="border">
         <img class="scale-with-grid" src="{% static 'images/Magic/4th Edition/Armageddon.full.jpg' %}" />
      </div>
      <center><h5 class="noline"><a href="#">{{card.set}}</a></h5></center>
   </div>
   <div class="shadow"></div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whit the help of Gocht I got it to work with

```
    {% with card.set|slugify as image_path %}
        {% with 'images/Magic/'|add:image_path|add:'/Armageddon.full.jpg' as image_path %}
            <img class="scale-with-grid" src="{% static image_path %}" />
        {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<img class="scale-with-grid" src="{% static 'images/Magic/{{ card.set }}/Armageddon.full.jpg' %}" />
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments, you could try this:

```
{% with 'images/Magic/'|add:card.set|add:'/Armageddon.full.jpg' as image_path %}
    <img class="scale-with-grid" src="{% static image_path %}" />
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks but that is adding a space after the value in card.set that is not in the other card.set.

Comment: @Paddy your `card.set` variable comes with this space from your view, I guess. Can you test it by printing `card.set` in your view?

Comment: The values have no space in the view

Comment: You can try with [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) template filter "_Also strips leading and trailing whitespace._" -> `{{ card.set|slugify }}`

Comment: That worked thanks. I will have to use - in place of a space in my image folders but that is fine.

Comment: sorry I never checked the link from the html, {% static 'images/Magic/{{card.set|slugify}}/Armageddon.full.jpg' %} trys to get the image from /static/images/Magic/%7B%7Bcard.set%7Cslugify%7D%7D/Armageddon.full.jpg

Comment: @Paddy Wow, let's try this please: `{% static 'images/Magic/'|add:card.set|add:'/Armageddon.full.jpg' %}`

Comment: That gives /static/images/Magic/4th%20Edition%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/Armageddon.full.jpg

Comment: that one gives /static/images/Magic/4th%20Edition%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/Armageddon.full.jpg

Comment: @Paddy I am not sure, but maybe you can't use the name `set`, please, try changing the name, and print the value in other place in your template to make sure of its value.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work with {% with card.set|slugify as image_path %}
             {% with 'images/Magic/'|add:image_path|add:'/Armageddon.full.jpg' as image_path %}
              <img class="scale-with-grid" src="{% static image_path %}" />
             {% endwith %}
            {% endwith %}

Comment: You card `card.set` value contains not url characteres, please the next time consider giving more information. Good for you!